# Bootstrap 3 carousel Positioning not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with the carousel i have created for a certain website. the carousel is workinglike it MUST in all the browsers i have tested it on except for Mozilla firefox version  25.0
Here is an image of what is happening[image]

if anyone has ever had a simalar problem i would like to know how they solved it, thanks
here is the code for the carousel

```
<!-- Carousel================================================== -->
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="images/slide_pics/1.png" alt="First slide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Example headline.</h1>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/slide_pics/2.jpg"  alt="Second slide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/slide_pics/3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

Here is the css am using

```
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
padding-bottom: 40px;
color: #5a5a5a;
}



/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
position: relative;
z-index: 15;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
margin-bottom: 0px;

/* Negative margin to pull up carousel. 90px is roughly margins and height of navbar. */
margin-top: 0px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
height: 400px;
margin-top:-10px;
background-color: #ccc;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: i have included the html and the css

Comment: Awesome, Upvoted as it's a better question now ;)

Comment: With your HTML and CSS, I don't see any difference between the normal FF and the nightly v27.0a1. Nor with other browsers. It is nothing like your screenshot though. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym8Na/)

Comment: it's working well on other browsers but on mozilla firefox version 25.0 it's still giving me that error. @Mr Lister.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not necessarily an answer here, more of a debugging hint... but when I'm faced with issues like this I add a 1px border to each item after your current css, but in a different colour i.e.

```
.navbar-wrapper {1px solid purple;}
.carousel {border: 1px solid black;}
.carousel-caption {border: 1px solid yellow;}
.carousel .item {border: 1px solid blue;}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {border: 1px solid red;}
```

Once thats done you'll see who the 'culprit' is - you'll most likely have to specify margin-left: 0px; for that element, as it seems like Firefox is inheriting the margin from a parent element in error. Then just take out the crazy borders!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would have never thought about this. It turns out it was the left border that was causing the problem in Mozilla Firefox 25.0.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I found the issue to be with the carousel.

```
.carousel { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Fixed the issue.

Firefox 20 (Mac)
Bootstrap 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

I solved with only just it:

```
.carousel {
  border-top: 1px solid #000
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it. May i wonder why ? Why on earth a top border has anything to do with an element being positioned wrong?

Comment: The problem still exists in Version 41.0.1

Answer (score 1):

```
.carousel {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```